# Bluetooth frequency-hopping advantages

Tags: frequency, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

i'm learning now the about Bluetooth (and BLE) and feel I need some explanation what the advantages of using frequency-hopping method. Can anyone please explain me in simple words (with examples, please) what we earn from the frequency-hopping? i know it should minimize interference, but don't understand how and why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequency hopping radios have a bunch of possible carrier frequencies that they can use for communicating. The receiving end of the link has to hop in sync with the transmitter and this means being able to predict correctly where to "move" its carrier frequency and when. This is usually accomplished by a "table" held in software at each end and some mechanism for keeping in sync.

If the pair of radios "fail" to communicate on one particular hop, there is a mechanism that allows both to recover from this fail and, importantly, that particular hop frequency is "marked" as temporarily unsuitable. Thus there is an algorithm at both ends that causes the "table" to evolve.

The upshot is that both ends of the link are evolving a "hop" table and that table contains frequencies that are generally the best to use to avoid data loss from interferers.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other posters, frequency hopping is a transmission technique where the transmitter "hops" between different frequencies with the aim of improving the transmission performance.On the receiver side there are two ways the receiver can receive the information - coherently or more commonly incoherently.

In coherent detection the receiver knows the hopping sequence so the receiver just hops in sync with the receiver and gets the transmitted data.In incoherent detection the receiver uses a maximum likelihood (ML) detector to figure out which frequency data was transmitted in.The ML detector basically just looks at which frequency band has the highest energy/power and picks that as the transmission frequency.

The big advantage of using this technique is improved transmission performance - If one frequency has a high amount of channel fading you can just avoid that frequency and hop between the other frequencies.But it is VERY important to realise that for this advantage to be realised the separation between the hopping channels has to be greater than the coherence bandwidth of the channel, if the separation is lower than the coherence bandwidth adjacent frequencies will be highly correlated and will thus suffer similar fading, making it useless to hop between them.

As for jamming, In order to use a purely frequency hopping based transmission scheme to prevent jamming, you would need to jump between frequencies with high levels of separation to prevent an intruder of using a jammer to just Jam all your signals.This is often not possible as you are usually limited to using a very small frequency band for transmission e.g 2.40GHz to 2.49GHz.A jammer could easily just jam that entire range of frequencies and render your transmission scheme useless.This problem is usually solved by using frequency hopping along with a another technique called "spreading" which helps prevent Jamming, you can look up spreading if you are interested to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the 1940s Hedy Lamarr (a very famous actress in the day) came up with the idea of frequency hopping for controlling torpedos.

[image]

This prevented frequency jamming of the guidance controls and so inadvertently invented the basis for cell phones and wi-fi.

Basically if one frequency channel is 'jammed' you detect the error and jump to another clear channel.